# How to generate a pdf using Django

Tags: pdf-generation, django-1.9

I am using Django 1.9. I am making an app which outputs an inventory as PDF.
Also using this library I can preview the pdf before finally outputting it. Which library can I use for this? Any suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ReportLab** is a library that outputs PDF files dynamically using Django views. You can go through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-pdf/ to learn more about it.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanx :)